# Moving wordpress dev theme from pc to mac locally

Tags: php, wordpress, mamp

I've been working on a wordpress theme locally on PC and i now want to move it over to mac to continue development as i can be more mobile on my laptop. Here are the steps i've read up on, and followed..

**Step 1.** Download the database 'wordpress' from my PC local server which is XAMP. So i go into phpmyadmin and download the sql file.

**Step 2.** Copy the theme folder of my custom theme i am developing.

**Step 3.** Load MAMP for the mac and go into phpmyadmin and IMPORT the .sql file i just got from the PC. Which works fine, it imports, and i can see everything.Thumbs up.

**Step 4.** I then go into some of the options tables and change the port on the url so that it's not longer referencing 8080 and instead 8888 which my mamp seems to use.

Visiting localhost:8888 displays my homepage, including styles and pages. Only thing missing is images which is expected. However, clicking any of the pages doesn't load anything. I just get page does not exist. I am certain the url is wrong still.

Anyway, i then try and login using the user previous set on the PC, which i checked imported and it did. But it constantly says my password is wrong when it's not. Do i need to somehow recreate a new user, or edit some properties?

So i cant login as my user, and i can't seem to access anything but the homepage.

Answer (score 0):

In your MAMP Prefrences change the port from `8888` to `80`

then open up your wordpress database table and go to the 'options' table - make sure the url says localhost and not localhost:8888.

that should do it

Comment: I did try this, however still getting issues logging in and accessing anything other than the homepage

Comment: Yep, just to change the ports

Comment: you need to go into your wordpress database then click on the 'wp_options' table then edit 'siteurl' and make sure its localhost